# "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" in MILU, a mutation testing tool for c

Tags: c, coredump, mutation-testing

To generate some great mutants of C programs, I cloned the Milu from [GitHub](https://github.com/yuejia/Milu), successfully compiled and run its example, just like the `Compilation in Ubuntu` and `Example` said.
However, when I wanted to generate mutants of my c file, I process the c file using `gcc -E` and run Milu, then `core dump`

```
gcc -E myfile.c > myfile
$MILU_PATH/bin/milu -v --exec-strategy=mut-1st myfile
```

> because this fault is so easy to trigger and the c file need .h, so I don't put the code here, you can use any other .c files to trigger it.

Then I use `gdb` to show the details of the fault.

```
gdb -c core $MILU_PATH/bin/milu
where
```

it shows

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x0804ec5f in print_source_unexposed_expr ()
#1  0x0804f08c in print_source_expr ()
#2  0x0804f2da in print_source_binary_operator ()
#3  0x0804f039 in print_source_expr ()
#4  0x0804e41a in print_source_call_expr ()
#5  0x0804f148 in print_source_expr ()
#6  0x080500dc in print_source_cstyle_cast_expr ()
#7  0x0804f166 in print_source_expr ()
#8  0x0804f319 in print_source_binary_operator ()
#9  0x0804f7ce in print_source_stmt ()
#10 0x0804e546 in print_source_compound_stmt ()
#11 0x0804e8a8 in print_source_function_decl ()
#12 0x0804d3b3 in ASTNode_print_source ()
#13 0x080540a7 in ASTUnit_print ()
#14 0x08056b0f in mutant_save ()
#15 0x0805885f in mutants_save ()
#16 0x080566a8 in milu_multi_process_mutants ()
#17 0x08055ba8 in milu_save_mutants ()
#18 0x08049e29 in main ()
```

Go into the $MILU_PATH, I found almost all of this functions were in `$MILU_PATH/src/mutation/`. One of them is

```
void ASTUnit_print(ASTUnit * au, PrintMode mode, FILE * output)
{
    ASTNode  * ast = au->ast;

    switch(mode)
    {
    case PrintDot:
    {
        ASTNode_print_dot(ast, output);
        break;
    }
    case PrintSource:
    {
        ASTNode_print_source(ast, output);
        break;
    }
    case PrintHtml:
    {
        ASTNode_print_html(ast, output);
        break;
    }

    default:
    {

        g_log ("Milu",G_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING,"Unknown print mode") ;

        break;
    }
    }
}
```

I don't know why these functions cause the fault. Hope there someone to help me.

Comment: Hey Tool Ply, two things to note: 1) This tool does not seem to be popular - I would recommend you to ask the author directly either via mail or issue on Github - it is unlikely that you will get an answer here. 2) There is another tool for mutation testing: [Mull](https://github.com/mull-project/mull). Make sure to check it out - it is in active development and it has a very good support of C (I am one of the developers).

Comment: Thank you. You are right. in fact, the issues in Milu github has been not answered for several years. Thank you again, it indeed help me.

Comment: hmm, I notice that Mull supports four mutators from now. Is that right? it may be not enough. 

Comment: Let's not go off topic here. If you have questions about Mull, it has a Slack channel on a README page.